# Save and restore form position and size using only NormalPosition from GetWindowPlacement

Tags: .net, winforms, winapi, window-management, window-position

In .NET Framework 4.6 and Windows Forms, I have a borderless form, without title bar and without minimize and maximize buttons, resizable (using custom code).

I'd like to save and restore the form location and size using [GetWindowPlacement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowplacement) and [SetWindowPlacement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowplacement).

I'm getting this kind of values from `GetWindowPlacement`:

```
<WindowPlacement>
  <Length>44</Length>
  <Flags>0</Flags>
  <ShowCmd>1</ShowCmd>
  <MinPosition>
    <X>-1</X>
    <Y>-1</Y>
  </MinPosition>
  <MaxPosition>
    <X>-1</X>
    <Y>-1</Y>
  </MaxPosition>
  <NormalPosition>
    <Left>949</Left>
    <Top>839</Top>
    <Right>1882</Right>
    <Bottom>1054</Bottom>
  </NormalPosition>
</WindowPlacement>
```

My form/window doesn't have minimize and maximize buttons, for all intended purposes it's not designed to be minimized/maximized, so it should always be restored to its normal window state.

Therefore I'm thinking only to save the `NormalPosition` rectangle from the `WindowPlacement` to application settings.

When loading the form I intent do create a `WindowPlacement` structure with the `NormalPosition` fields loaded from settings, and fill the other values with defaults (`ShowCmd` to 1, `MinPosition` to -1, -1, etc.)

What worries me is this quote from [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-windowplacement):

> The coordinates used in a WINDOWPLACEMENT structure should be used
> only by the GetWindowPlacement and SetWindowPlacement functions.

Should I be worried? Can I get some kind of weird behavior with my plan of only saving the `NormalPosition`?

Comment: That's not the full quote. The full quote contains rationale, and explains why you need not be worried.

Answer (score 0):

> The coordinates used in a WINDOWPLACEMENT structure should be used
> only by the GetWindowPlacement and SetWindowPlacement functions.

The above sentence in the document explains the reason for this problem. This is due to the different coordinate system used. If your window does not have the `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW` style, `rcNormalPosition` contains the workspace coordinates.

> Workspace coordinates differ from screen coordinates in that they take
> the locations and sizes of application toolbars (including the
> taskbar) into account. Workspace coordinate (0,0) is the upper-left
> corner of the workspace area, the area of the screen not being used by
> application toolbars.

If the taskbar is at the top of the screen, assume the height is 40, the upper left corner of the `rcNormalPosition` you get is (0,0), then its screen coordinates is (0,0). (The taskbar on the left is similar)

[image]

If this behavior affects your application, you should consider calling `SetWindowPlacement` with the `WindowPlacement` that saved when your form is loaded.